# Magento 2 removing shipping methods if product attribute exists

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

If a customer places an order with a specific product attribute then I need to remove a particular shipping method. Does anyone know which method I would need to write a plugin for to overwrite which methods are available?

Answer (score 0):

You could place an `after` or `around` plugin on `Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface` `getAllowedMethods()`.  You'd load the cart, check for your product, then modify the return result.